# Differences between Dovecot and cyrus

Tags: linux, email, postfix-mta, dovecot, cyrus

What are the differences between dovecot and cyrus SASL which is being used with postfix ?
Which is the commonly used one nowadays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://chiralsoftware.com/linux-system-administration/secure-relaying-postfix-sasl-tls-dovecot.seam as both of them are quite capable of providing security in terms of authentication but dovecot is much simpler to configure and is now being used widely. The link mentioned would give you more insight.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: can i use both SASL together? that is cyrus and Dovecot together?